# Pass in structure correctly (js)

Tags: javascript, bixby

Face some problem in passing data into structure correctly

This is the structure

[image]

And this is how i pass in

```
var dates = require('dates');

module.exports.function = function getStart() {
  var optionList = [
  {option : "Latest headlines"},
  {option : "Latest news"},
  {option : "Top headlines"},
  {option : "Top news"}
]
  var currentTimeHour = dates.ZonedDateTime.getHour
  var timePeriod = "";

  if (currentTimeHour == 0 && currentTimeHour <= 12) {
    timePeriod = "M"//Morning
  } else if (currentTimeHour >= 13 && currentTimeHour <= 20) {
    timePeriod = "A"//Afternoon
  } else if (currentTimeHour <=23){
    timePeriod = "N"//Night
  }else {
    timePeriod = null
  }

  var menu = {};

  optionList.option.forEach(function(value,index,array){
    menu[index] = {
      whatuserwant : optionList[index],
      timePeriod : timePeriod
    }

  });

  return menu

}
```

And error pop out

[image]

Where did i gone wrong ,

And for extra question, is my if-else condition for currentTimeHour wrote correctly?

Regards.

Comment: optionList is an array, it doesn't have an `.option` key. You have to write `optionList.forEach()`

Comment: Also, `currentTimeHour == 0 && currentTimeHour <= 12` will be satisfied only if `currentTimeHour==0`; It should be `currentTimeHour >= 0 && currentTimeHour <= 12`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think my problem on js side had been solve, will post another question for the part on bixby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach is defined on arrays where as optionList.option is not an array.

Try using only optionList

```
optionList.forEach(function(value,index,array){
        menu[index] = {
          whatuserwant : value.option,
          timePeriod : timePeriod
        }
      });
```